# Can a lander on an airless body BE a rover?

Tags: landing, design, rovers, lander

Rovers normally roll off a lander, or are otherwise deployed by one. When I look at the design of [ATHLETE](https://www-robotics.jpl.nasa.gov/systems/system.cfm?System=11), it isn't hard to imagine a rocket engine bolted underneath it, and ATHLETE's legs doing the job of absorbing landing impact and steadying itself. Given ATHLETE's robotic abilities, it also isn't hard to imagine it then unbolting the rocket engine and driving away from it. This seems like it would allow a mass savings. Is it that it is too hard to protect against the heat and vapors of the engines? Have designs like this been considered?

[image: ATHLETE robotic rover design]

[image: mock-up of ATHLETE as lander]

Comment: But why should your rover carry around the extra weight of the now-useless rocket engine, fuel tanks, and associated machinery?

Comment: @jamesqf It doesn't - it unbolts them and leaves them behind.

Comment: So you have a possibly quite complicated unbolting mechanism rather than just driving off a ramp, or (in the case of Curiousity) just severing a cable?  Without detailed engineering studies, I suspect not much advantage.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, though not necessarily as the landing pads. One of its main imagined applications was to take payloads off of landers, as shown in the cartoon below. A single Athlete could do this for several payloads at the same site so that you wouldn't need another Athlete for every lander.

[image: athlete]

Also note that Curiosity landed on its wheels, so it is a lander that is a rover. (Once that system got to the terminal descent phase, Mars was essentially airless to that system.) The rocket engines were above, cut away, and flew away so there was no need to unbolt the engines from the rover.

Comment: Where did that great illustration come from?

Comment: [Popular Science](http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2013-01/meet-athlete-nasas-robot-moon-walker).

Comment: By the way, each of those three-wheeled Athlete pieces you see in the cartoon were called Triathletes.

Comment: Yes, i saw that :) I've read the short JPL webpage about it, and it was talked about a lot in a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4N8QmPAcnk&feature=youtu.be) by Brian Wilcox through Keck. I'm planning to make an animated digital model of it. I'll probably make that version capable of full walking motion too, which i sort of figured would be added to the design eventually. Really great rover.

Comment: I noticed the wheel that "7" points to shows a lot of flexion going over the rock. Is this an image error, or are the wheels extremely soft / flexible, for better traction?

Comment: The wheels are flexible. Though they are not at all "extremely soft". They are quite stiff, but there is a _lot_ of weight on them. You would not be able to flex them with your hands.

Comment: The image of the flexing wheel is inaccurate in that the rover depicted carries no payload. The wheel wouldn't flex that much under the rover's weight alone.