# Which rover(s) didn't have wheels?

Tags: rovers

The question [Wheels vs. tracks for rovers](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/668/12102) and [Does new technology make it advantageous to have walking rovers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17610/12102) ask about the possible use of treads or legs instead of wheels on rovers from a speculative point of view.

But which rover already on another solar system body *didn't have any wheels?*

Answer (score 7):

The list of successful rover missions is [short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rover_(space_exploration)):

- Moon: LRV, Lunokhod, Yutu
- Mars: Sojourner, Spirit, Opportunity, Curiosity

All of them have wheels.

The Soviet Union built two walking rovers (using 2 skis) ([Prop-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2#Prop-M_Rover)), for the Mars-2 and Mars-3 missions. Both missions [failed](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/is-there-any-chance-mars-3s-prop-m-rover-deployed-automatically-and-roved) before these rovers could be deployed.

Comment: Yep, they are indeed wheel-less rovers that are *on Mars*, but as you point out, probably not successfully deployed from their landers, although I don't know if that is absolutely certain in both cases, or just highly likely.

Comment: Can I get you to change "None" to something more accurate? There are in fact two Prop-M rovers on mars, correct? They were probably not deployed, nor did they rove, but there are still two wheel-less rovers on Mars. It's not like the rocket blew up on the launch pad or something.

Comment: According to Wikipedia,[The (Mars 2) descent module became the first man-made object to impact the surface of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2#Entry.2C_descent.2C_and_crash_landing), and [...the (Mars 3) lander achieved a soft landing at 45°S 202°E and began operations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_3#Entry.2C_descent.2C_landing.2C_and_transmission_failure) and there appears to be independent photographic evidence of the lander, retro-rockets, heat shield and parachute.

Comment: Radio contact with Mars 3 was lost, that can be considered a mission failure. But I'm still looking for an answer to [Is there any chance Mars-3's Prop-M rover deployed automatically and “roved”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21709/12102)

Comment: OK @called2voyage has [removed any lingering uncertainty](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21734/12102). Without radio contact from Earth, the Prop-M rover would not be deployed. There are two on Mars, one in a crash landing, one in landing that went as expected, but not deployed. You may want to link to his answer here, it's a good one!

Answer (score 7):

The [MINERVA-II](https://www.hayabusa2.jaxa.jp/en/topics/20180919e/) rovers, 1 and 2, deployed from JAXA's Hayabusa-2 onto the asteroid 162173 Ryugu, lacked wheels.  They traversed the surface by [hopping](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-06808-0), by swinging an internal counterweight.  Wheels or treads wouldn't have worked in Ryugu's weak gravity.

They were deployed only after this question was first asked, though.

Comment: I think that wheel-less rovers are going to be "a thing" in the future, so while it might be impractical to constantly update answers here each time a new one is deployed, I think it's important that a canonical answer exist here for "hoppers". Related: [How might one redesign a “Curiosity-class” rover for a mission to Vesta or Ceres?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48928/12102) and [Can a lander on an airless body BE a rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14214/12102) and [Does new technology make it advantageous to have walking rovers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17610/12102)

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness sake, we should remember the dearly beloved Ingenuity Helicopter, which is very much a rover and non-wheeled.

Comment: Yes indeed, great catch!

Answer (score 4):

There was also a jumping rover for Phobos
Mission failed before this rover could be deployed.
[image: Phobos rover]
At  7:18

A universal rover for Mars and Venus was also developed with a wind generator as a source of electrical energy. This rover could walk when needed. Due to the collapse of the USSR, these missions to Mars and Venus were never launched.
[image: Venera-Mars rover]
At

Comment: Your answers are always informative, it's great that you can reference so much information from history and bring it to people's attention. *Thank you!*

Comment: The jumping robot reminds me of [daddy long legs spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pholcus_phalangioides).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like @Hobbes nailed it right off with [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21694/12102). There are two Prop-M rovers on Mars. While Mars-2 crash-landed, Mars-3 landed and began transmitting. However, thanks to some excellent research by @called2voyage, we can see that because the rovers would not be deployed without [explicit radio instruction](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21734/12102), neither rovers were ever able to "rove" on Mars. Nevertheless it seems they are there, in some form or other.

I'll have to think of something harder for a puzzler next time.

I'll add this cute GIF and photo, both found at the Wikipedia article for [Mars 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_3). According to the article, the rover was to remain attached by an umbilical to the lander, and do some local exploration while monitored and sometimes filmed by the lander.

[image: Prop-1 Mars rover]

**above:** GIF of how the Prop-M rover uses it's "skis" to walk. Linked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_3), from [Giphy](https://giphy.com/gifs/technology-mars-xXVrw6khBFdIY).

[image: Prop-1 Mars rover]

**above:** Mars Prop-M rover from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mars_propm_rover.jpg).